# How to sequentially execute sql statements in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, foreach, sequential

I am trying to execute list of SQL commands sequentially with below code. but i could see that sequence is not guaranteed from below approach. what woould be the right approach ?

```
deletegrpquery = 'delete FROM grp where grp_id=(?)';
deleteuserassociations = 'delete FROM grp_usr where grp_id=(?)';
deleteexpensesofgrp = 'delete FROM exp where exp_grp=(?)';
deletepaidbyentries = 'delete FROM paidby where paid_exp in ( select exp_id from exp where exp_grp=(?))';
deleteapplicabletoentries = 'delete FROM applicableto where applicable_exp in ( select exp_id from exp where exp_grp=(?)';
deletesettlements = 'delete from settlements where settlement_grp=(?)';
cleanup_applicable = 'delete FROM applicableto where applicable_exp not in (select exp_id from exp)';
cleanup_paidby = 'delete FROM applicableto where applicable_exp not in (select exp_id from exp)';

querylistfordeletegrp = [deletepaidbyentries, deleteapplicabletoentries, deletesettlements, deleteuserassociations, deletegrpquery,deleteexpensesofgrp, cleanup_applicable, cleanup_paidby];

angular.forEach(querylistfordeletegrp, function(query) {
  DB.query(query, [grp_id]).then(function(result) {
      console.log(query);
  });
})
```

Comment: I don't know much JS, but it seems to me that you should wait for a query to finish, then execute next one in its `then` callback. And so on. There may be libraries to facilitate this stuff.

Comment: nested thens ? i think it is too nested :P looking for a cleaner way .

Comment: First of all I don't recommend querying the database directly from Javascript (client side). It's extremely dangerous. Database calls and queries must be managed server side.

Comment: @swordf1zh . Thanks! , but this is for a offline mobile app

Comment: What's your DB framework, can you put all those calls into a stored procedure and just call that procedure once?  Also, looks like `deleteapplicabletoentries` has a missing right-paren at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var promise = $q.when();
angular.forEach(querylistfordeletegrp, function(query) {
  promise = promise.then(function() {
    return DB.query(query, [grp_id]);
  });
});
```

Comment: But that did not solve the problem. sequence still not achieved

Comment: I forgot to return from the callback. Try again with the return.

Comment: Working example (where the DB query is simulated by a timeout). Open your console to see what happens: http://plnkr.co/edit/MZAcQJKeVGIV561vBX0E?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Make a function executeNextQuery() and call it recursively from inside the then()

Answer (score 0):

$q.serial helped to achieve this in a cleaner way http://www.codeducky.org/q-serial/

```
        deletegrpquery = 'delete FROM grp where grp_id=(?)';
        deleteuserassociations = 'delete FROM grp_usr where grp_id=(?)';
        deleteexpensesofgrp = 'delete FROM exp where exp_grp=(?)';
        deletepaidbyentries = 'delete FROM paidby where paid_exp in ( select exp_id from exp where exp_grp=(?))';
        deleteapplicabletoentries = 'delete FROM applicableto where applicable_exp in ( select exp_id from exp where exp_grp=(?))';
        deletesettlements = 'delete from settlements where settlement_grp=(?)';
        cleanup_applicable = 'delete FROM applicableto where applicable_exp not in (select exp_id from exp)';
        cleanup_paidby = 'delete FROM paidby where paid_exp not in (select exp_id from exp)';
        querylistfordeletegrp = [deletepaidbyentries, deleteapplicabletoentries, deletesettlements, deleteuserassociations, deletegrpquery, deleteexpensesofgrp, cleanup_applicable, cleanup_paidby];
        // solution
        var tasks = querylistfordeletegrp.map(function(query) {
            return function() {
                return DB.query(query, [grp_id]);
            };
        });
        $q.serial(tasks);
```